# etherbase missing: etherbase must be explicitly specified

Tags: polygon-pos

We are trying to run a validator node.

But we notice some issues on the logs.

We are constantly getting these messages on logs

etherbase missing: etherbase must be explicitly specified

We have followed all the steps according to the documentation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, the signer address that is used to mine must be added inside `miner.etherbase` section in the `config.toml` file.

Alternatively, if you are not a part of the active validator set you wouldn't be mining blocks so you can disable the mine parameter that should fix the issue.